# Trouble Editing Categories for Admins

Tags: categories

I'm having some difficulties having clients adding/editing categories within entries.

As the Super Admin, I can simply open an entry, click Categories and can add/edit categories without any troubles. When I log in as an Admin account type however, I am unable to add categories. When I click the link, I get two JS errors, one being a 500 Internal Server error, the other, "Uncaught ReferenceError: $loading is not defined."

Any ideas as to why this is not affecting Super Admins, but only the Admins?

We're using EE 2.5.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SuperAdmins have access to everything, hence no issues.

First step is to make sure the Admin group has permissions to add/edit categories enabled. The setting is called **"[Can edit and add new categories](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#can-edit-and-add-new-categories)"** and it's located here: Members ‣ Member Groups ‣ Create/Edit. I you want them to be able to delete categories, enable "Can delete categories" as well.

Second step is to make these two changes to the [**category group**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/category_create_group.html#can-edit-categories) settings as well.

Once done, your Admin group should be able to manage categories correctly.

Comment: Ah ha! I was missing the second step.

Thanks!!

Also, thanks for the response. Sorry it took me a few days, I've not received any notifications.

Comment: You probably have to setup notifications. I think they are off by default. You're welcome!